# Where to Linq Foreach GroupBy

Tags: c#, sql, linq, foreach, where-clause

how can i add a where clause to my Linq Foreach Statement?
this is my Linq:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Select(x => new 
                {
                 Rid = x.Rid,
                 Total = x.Total
                 })
                 .GroupBy(l => l.Rid) //and then grouping
                 .Select(z => new
                 {
                 Turno = z.Key,
Total = Decimal.Round(z.Sum(l => l.Total), 0)
                  }))
                 {
                <input value="@item)" />
                  }
```

I want to put a where clause where it evaluate a global variable named 'Date', im new to Linq so how can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's off Model class, it's just

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.Date == this.Date)
                .Select(x => new 
                {
                 Rid = x.Rid,
                 Total = x.Total
                 })
                 .GroupBy(l => l.Rid) //and then grouping
                 .Select(z => new
                 {
                 Turno = z.Key,
Total = Decimal.Round(z.Sum(l => l.Total), 0)
                  }))
                 {
                <input value="@item)" />
                  }
```

this will filter Model by date. If you have your date variable named differently, obviously just change it.